# Is there a web-based way to edit md files graphically in real-time?

Tags: github, wysiwyg

I'm searching for a tool which helps me edit the README.md files for my github projects.

I know that there are offline programs which let me to do this, but I am hopefully looking for a web-based WYSIWYG solution so I can have a tab on my browser to work on the md file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're looking for [dillinger.io](http://www.dillinger.io/)

Not only does it let you view your md code along-side with your html graphical representation of it, but it also has a resulting look very similar to that of github's.

[image]

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Thanks, it's exactly what I was looking for.